# A python function to shift the positions of a vowel by 2 places?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, dictionary

r task is to shift the vowels by two positions contained in the string, where vowels are
the symbols a e i o u (and their capitalised versions A E I O U), If the input is "a cat", the output is "i cit"

```
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
vowel=['a','e','i','o','u']

mapper = dict(zip(vowels, vowels[1:] + [vowels[0]]))
message=input('enter mesaage')

new_message = ""
for letter in message:
    if letter not in vowels:
        new_message += letter
    else:
        i = vowels.index(letter)
        i+=2
        new_message += vowels[i]
print(new_message)
```

this throws an index out of bound error

Comment: use your mapper. `new_message += mapper[mapper[letter]]`

Comment: Right after `i+=2`, write `i = i % 5`. Or, you could change your `vowels` array to `['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'a', 'e']`. Both ways print the same result.

Comment: thank you but my code fails every time i have to shift the vowel places multiple times depending on the vowel occurences eg If a vowel is repeated multiple times the vowel is shifted by multiple steps. The number of steps
is equal to the number of repeated vowels + 1. For instance, "mood" becomes "meed". ?? @flakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a function `count_repetition` which tells you how many consecutive vowels there are starting at any position. This is also the number of vowels in `vowels` array that you should skip. The new vowel can be found using `vowels[(steps+i+1)%size]` where `size` is the length of `vowels` array and `i` is the index of the original vowel.

```py
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]


def count_repetition(message, i):
    # counts the number of consecutive chars starting at index i
    count = 1
    for j in range(i, len(message)-1):
        if(message[j] == message[j+1]):
            count += 1
        else:
            return count
    return count


message = input('enter message: ')
new_message = ""
size = len(vowels)
j = 0

while(j < len(message)):
    letter = message[j]
    if letter.lower() not in vowels:
        new_message += letter
        j += 1
    else:
        i = vowels.index(letter)
        # count number of consecutive letters
        steps = count_repetition(message, j)
        for _ in range(0, steps):
            new_message += vowels[(steps+i+1) % size]
        j += steps

print(new_message)
# meeduuu -> muudooo
# a cat -> i cit
# meed -> muud
# maad -> mood
```

### Version 2 preserving capitalisation

```py
def count_repetition(message, i):
    # counts the number of consecutive chars starting at index i, ignoring
    # uppercase/lowercase
    count = 1
    for j in range(i, len(message)-1):
        if(message[j].lower() == message[j+1].lower()):
            count += 1
        else:
            return count
    return count


def changeLetterCase(letter, toUpper):
    # changes letter to lowercase or uppercase
    # changeLetterCase('a', True) => 'A'
    # changeLetterCase('A', False) => a'
    if toUpper:
        return letter.upper()
    return letter.lower()


def solve(message):
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    SIZE = len(vowels)

    new_message = ""
    j = 0

    while(j < len(message)):

        letter = message[j].lower()
        isUpperCase = message[j].isupper()

        if letter not in vowels:
            new_message += changeLetterCase(letter, isUpperCase)
            j += 1
        else:
            # get position of current vowel in `vowels`
            i = vowels.index(letter)

            # count number of consecutive letters
            steps = count_repetition(message, j)

            # get replacement vowel
            new_vowel = vowels[(steps+i+1) % SIZE]

            # update consecutive vowels taking into consideration
            # uppercase/lowercase
            for step in range(0, steps):
                isUpperCase = message[j].isupper()

                new_message += changeLetterCase(
                    new_vowel, isUpperCase)
                j += 1
    return new_message


print(solve('mUUd'))  # mIId
print(solve('maaApp'))  # muuUpp
print(solve('a cat'))  # i cit
print(solve('meed'))  # muud
print(solve('maaaad'))  # maaaad
```

Comment: thank you this pretty much answers my question. Do you have any idea how could i preserve the capitalization in the code if i wanted to ??

Comment: @KabirGujral  It is possible to preserve capitalisation. I've added a second version in my post.